# Apocorubik's Cube (10,000 blocks across): How long to solve if a quarter turn takes 2.8 seconds?

Tags: problem-solving, rubiks-cube

Suppose you have a Rubik's cube, $10,000$ blocks across (so, $600,000,000$
total tiles), scrambled.  Assuming an ideal solving algorithm, approximately how long will the cube take to be solved, given one quarter turn can be made every 2.8 seconds?

Comment: Do ou have some reason to think this is known?  Or possible to compute with existing technology?

Comment: @GEdgar I know that the optimal algorithm for a rubiks cube of arbitrary size might not be known, but I think an approximation is possible.

Comment: The so-called ["God's Number"](https://cube20.org) —counting the number of moves required to solve the $3\times 3\times 3$ cube— is known to be $20$; the number of *quarter turns* (as opposed to *moves*) is reportedly $26$. So, make your best guess about how $26$ scales to a $10000\times 10000\times 10000$ cube, and multiply by $2.8$.

Comment: @Blue But how does the God's Number scale with cube size?  Its not just a linear scale.  God's number for 2 by 2 by 2s is 14.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5736 the asymptotic bound for God's Number on higher order cubes is:

$$\Theta(n^2/\log n)$$

But this is only asymptotic, so you can't just plug in $n$ and expect to get the exact right answer.  But we use it as a very loose approximation.  Since God's Number for $n=3$ is 26 (using quarter-turn metric), we can do:

$$
\frac{10000^2}{\log 10000} * \frac{\log 3}{3^2} * 26 = 34458757
$$

So to round off your question take that number, multiply it by 2.8s, and you get about 3.1 years.

Comment: +1. Since approximations are very loose anyway, this is a pointless nit-pick, but ... As mentioned in my comment, God's number counts *moves*; OP counts *quarter turns*. So, there's an additional "expected number of quarter turns" factor to consider.

Comment: How far off in either direction could this estimate be?  Is it within an order of magnitude?

Comment: @qazwsx there is really no way to tell... $\Theta$ notation really only says what will happen in the limit... but before that it can deviate an arbitrary amount.

Comment: @Blue thx amended

Comment: The end of section 4 of that paper gives an explicit lower bound: an $n \times n \times n$ cube requires at least $$\frac{\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor-1\right)^2}{\log_c (6n)} - 1$$ quarter-turns to solve, where $c=\frac{24!}{(4!)^6}$. For $n=10000$, this appears to work out to about $8 \cdot 10^7$ moves or a little over $7$ years. It looks like you could extract an explicit upper bound from the earlier bits of section 4 — it comes from an explicit solving algorithm — but it'd take more work.

Comment: @timidpueo: If I were using loose approximations, and found that an answer was 3.1, I don't think I could resist writing $\pi$. ;)

Comment: @Micah any luck?

Comment: @qazwsx: I haven't been looking at it much. I think that end of it would be worth writing an actual answer; the paper really isn't set up to make it easy.